# Error when using parameter pack with std::function

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++17, variadic-templates

I have this code:

```
#include <functional>
template<class T, class U>
void f(std::function<T(U)> g) {};
int main() {
    auto h = [](int x) {return x;};
    f<int, int>(h);
}
```

This code works. But when I use parameter pack (code below), it fails... why?

```
#include <functional>
template<class T, class...U>
void f(std::function<T(U...)> g) {};
int main() {
    auto h = [](int x) {return x;};
    f<int, int>(h);
}
```

Using `std::function<int(int)>` instead of `auto` made it work with parameter pack.

Comment: This: `template<class T, class U> void f(std::function<T(U)>)` is never what you want to do. I need to write a good canonical dupe target for this. Until then, I think the linked one works well enough.

Comment: @Barry that would be very helpful. I've been bitten by it too; `std::function` feels so magic sometimes that it's easy to disregard that its type erasure doesn't mix well with type deduction and overloading ambiguities. That said, I've had great success with CTAD as in `std::function{some_lambda_object}` to deduce a parameter pack of arguments. I would love a detailed explanation of it all.